# How to convert from western date format to japanese date format?

Tags: java

I have a `String` of date. This date is in western date format. What I want is to have it in Japanese format.

```
String a = "2019-05-10";
DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendPattern("YYYY-MM-DD")
            .toFormatter(Locale.JAPAN);
String aa = LocalTime.parse(a, timeFormatter)
            .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY年MM月DD日", Locale.JAPAN));

System.out.println(aa);
```

current error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2019-05-10' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalTime from TemporalAccessor: {DayOfYear=10, MonthOfYear=5, WeekBasedYear[WeekFields[SUNDAY,1]]=2019},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.createError(Unknown Source)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.time.LocalTime.parse(Unknown Source)
    at testing.DatumTypeDecimal.main(DatumTypeDecimal.java:223)
Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain LocalTime from TemporalAccessor: {DayOfYear=10, MonthOfYear=5, WeekBasedYear[WeekFields[SUNDAY,1]]=2019},ISO of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.time.LocalTime.from(Unknown Source)
    at java.time.format.Parsed.query(Unknown Source)
    ... 3 more
```

Expected output:

```
2019年05月10日
```

Comment: Always post the COMPLETE stack trace when asking questions about exceptions in your code.

Comment: Probably try changing the local of the formatter to Japan rather then introducing the characters.  I'd also suggest that `YYYY-MM-DD` is not a valid formatter and you should be using `LocalDate` not `LocalTime`

Comment: Well, I changed it to LocalDate but still received the same errors

Comment: buddy, I gave you a working solution, but you deleted the question, just FYI...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the proper class for a date, which isn't `LocalTime` but `LocalDate`. In addition, your pattern is wrong due to upper case `Y` and `D`.

I have tried it the following way:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    String a = "2019-05-10";    // ISO date format
    String b = "2019-5-10";     // date format with only a single digit for month
    LocalDate ldA = LocalDate.parse(a, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE);
    LocalDate ldB = LocalDate.parse(b, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-M-dd"));
    // note the lower case year and day, month stays upper case
    System.out.println(ldA.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy年MM月dd日", Locale.JAPAN)));
    System.out.println(ldB.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy年MM月dd日", Locale.JAPAN)));
}
```

and that outputs

```
2019年05月10日
```

In order to store that in a `String`, just do

```
String myJapaneseDate = ldA.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy年MM月dd日", Locale.JAPAN));
```

**Edit:**

As requested, here is an example of using a method to (1) make the given `String` a valid ISO format and (2) return the `LocalDate` parsed from that.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    String a = "2019-05-10";    // ISO date format
    String b = "2019-5-10";     // date format with only a single digit for month
    LocalDate ldA = makeItIsoFormat(a);
    LocalDate ldB = makeItIsoFormat(b);
    // note the lower case year and day, month stays upper case
    System.out.println(ldA.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy年MM月dd日", Locale.JAPAN)));
    System.out.println(ldB.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy年MM月dd日", Locale.JAPAN)));
}

public static LocalDate makeItIsoFormat(String date) {
    // first, split the input String by a hyphon
    String[] splitDate = date.split("-");

    // check its length, it has to have 3 parts (year, month, day)
    if (splitDate.length != 3) {
        // if it has more or less parts, the date is considered invalid
        System.err.println("invalid date String provided");
    } else {
        // otherwise, check the amount of digits it has for month
        if (splitDate[1].length() == 1) {
            // and if it is just one, add a leading zero
            System.out.println("The given date \"" 
                    + date 
                    + "\" has a single digit for month, add leading zero");
            splitDate[1] = "0" + splitDate[1];
        }
    }

    /*
     * CONSIDER ADDING A CHECK FOR SINGLE-DIGIT DAYS, it is not yet included
     */

    // recreate the date String
    String isoDate = splitDate[0] + "-" + splitDate[1] + "-" + splitDate[2];
    // and return the parsed LocalDate
    return LocalDate.parse(isoDate, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE);
}
```

Comment: this works good but when I try it with input a = "2019-5-10" changing from two digits for months to single digit then I receive errors.

Comment: @Anonymous sure, for dates that have just one digit for a month, you have to use a slightly different pattern: `"yyyy年M月dd日"`. Unfortunately, there is no pattern that handles all the different formattings.

Comment: No, its not the part from the output but the input. Current DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE take yyyy-MM-dd and not yyyy-M-dd. Is there a way to make it take both single and double?

Comment: @Anonymous I don't think so, but see my edit. The output will of course stay the same for every valid `LocalDate`, but you have to parse them differently first. You need a second (and maybe more) patterns or you normalize the input `String` to fit the ISO format

Comment: I see. but is there a way to just include one input and then it will check which pattern of it and perform according. example if input "2019-5-10" it will automatically go to the ldB and not ldA. Vice versa too.

Comment: @Anonymous see my new edit, I have provided an example method that normalizes the amount of digits for month. It just does that and does not consider one-digit days! You could add that to the method.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, this requires a few steps...

First, get the input into a valid date container (ie `LocalDate`)

```
String input = "2019-05-10";
DateTimeFormatter inputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(input, inputFormatter);
```

Next, construct a date formatter which will be capable for formatting the date container to the format we want.  Note, I've used `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.FULL)` instead of supplying the pattern, as it can produce a better result

```
DateTimeFormatter outputFormatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
        .append(DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.FULL))
//                .appendPattern("yyyy年MM月dd日")
        .toFormatter(Locale.JAPAN);
```

Finally, format the date container...

```
String output = outputFormatter.format(localDate);
System.out.println(output);
```

And this will generate `2019年5月10日金曜日`

Also, for what it's worth, `FormatStye.LONG` generated `2019年5月10日` which seems to be more inline with your target exceptions

Comment: I think this does not exactly produce the desired/expected output due to a missing leading zero for the month digits.

Comment: Well, it’s using the internal considerations for the for at rather then a specific formatted, the nicety is, you can change the locale and it will continue working

Comment: I like the solution, I just wanted to point out that little flaw concerning the question. I think I will use that soon, too.

Comment: Compromises, compromises every where 

Answer (score 1):

You can do with 2 SimpleDateFormat

example:

```
String input = "2019-05-10";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(input);
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy年MM月dd日").format(date));
```

output :

```
2019年05月10日
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know other solutions for this, but I hope this code helps. 
the method only replaces the characters '-' then `append()` the last one.

```
public String japaneseFormat(String date){
   StringBuilder date =new StringBuilder(date);

   date.setCharAt(4,'年'); 
   date.setCharAt(7,'月');
   date.append("日");
   return date.toString();
}
```